# Como identificar elemento input detectado por enter

Tags: jquery

Al abrir un modal muestro una tabla de producto. Primero tiene dos filtros por codigo y por nombre respectivamente. Si hago click en enter estando en codigo o nombre pasa a un input que hay en la tabla donde se inserta la cantidad(hay uno por fila) y luego hay un mas que agrega al ticket.:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir el user filtra y luego se mueve en la tabla, con el tabulador va pasando los input de cantidad, es decir si encontro en la pantalla el producto hace enter y pasa al primer registro, y con Tab sigue hacia abajo.
El problema es que quiero con otro enter ejecutar el codigo de Agregarproducto(), es una funcion en el boton mas, pero solo funciona si estoy en el primer registro.:

```
(document).ready(function() {
    $(".modal").on("shown.bs.modal", function (e) {
   $(this).insertAfter($(".modal-backdrop"));
   setTimeout(function(){ 
     $('#cod').focus(); 
      $('#cod').on('keypress', function(event){

     if (event.keyCode ===13){

           $('#cant').focus();
         }
     });
      }, 500);
     $('#cant').on('keypress', function(event){

     if (event.keyCode ===13){
        var id=$(this).attr("name");

   agregarProducto(id);
         }
     });


  });

$(document).on('click', '#art', function(){

    $('.modal-body').load('content.html',function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');

    });

});



$(document).on('keydown', 'body', function(event) {

        if(event.keyCode==113){ //F2
        $('.modal-body').load('content.html',function(){

        $('#myModal').modal({show:true});

    });

         }

       if (event.keyCode==27){
            window.location.href="index.php?controller=ticket&action=index";
               $('#myModal').modal({show:false});

         }
     });
```

con el codigo de arriba muestro el modal ya sea con F2 o haciendo click en el menu. Luego detecto el click en cod, y como veran llamo a agregar producto.

Pero a su vez dentro de content.html (el modal) llamo a otro script conteniendo lo siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
listar();



var nombreBusqueda;

 $("#nombre").keyup(function() {
          if (event.keyCode ===13){

           $('#cant').focus();
         }else{


        nombreBusqueda=$("#nombre").val();
        filtrar(nombreBusqueda);
         }
    });
   $("#cod").keyup(function() {

        codBusqueda=$("#cod").val();
        filtrarcod(codBusqueda);
    });



});
function filtrarcod(dato){
        var filtrado=[];
        var existe;
    for(var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
 if (content[i].codalfa.toLowerCase().indexOf(dato.toLowerCase())!=-1) {
        filtrado.push(content[i]);


    }
}
     if (filtrado.length>0) {

            $("#resultadomodal tbody").empty();

            for (var i = 0; i < filtrado.length; i++) {

                var newRow =
                    "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].codalfa + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].nombre + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].marca + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].detalle + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].precio + "</td>" +
                         "<td>"+"<input type='text' name='"+filtrado[i].idproducto+"' id='cant' class='form-control input-sm-2' value='1' tabindex='3' placeholder='cant'/>" + "</td>" +


                     "<td>"+
" <a  class='btn btn-primary' onclick='agregarProducto("+filtrado[i].idproducto+");' name='agregar' >+</a></td>"+


                    "</tr>";

                $(newRow).appendTo("#resultadomodal tbody");                 
       }


}};
function filtrar(dato){
        var filtrado=[];
        var existe;
    for(var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    if (content[i].nombre.toLowerCase().indexOf(dato.toLowerCase())!=-1) {
        filtrado.push(content[i]);


    }
}
     if (filtrado.length>0) {

      $("#resultadomodal tbody").empty();

            for (var i = 0; i < filtrado.length; i++) {

                var newRow =
                    "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].codalfa + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].nombre + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].marca + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].detalle + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].precio + "</td>" +
                    "<td>"+"<input type='text' name='"+filtrado[i].idproducto+"' id='cant' class='form-control input-sm-2' value='1' tabindex='3' placeholder='cant'/>" + "</td>" +


                     "<td>"+
          " <a  class='btn btn-primary' onclick='agregarProducto("+filtrado[i].idproducto+");' name='agregar' >+</a></td>"+


                    "</tr>";

                $(newRow).appendTo("#resultadomodal tbody");                 
       }



}};
function listar(){

    tipofiltro="todos";
     $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "../gestionweb/includes/php/filtroP.php",
            data: { "tf": tipofiltro}, 
            dataType: "json",
            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success: function(data){
           content=data;
               for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                var newRow =
                    "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].codalfa + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].nombre + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].marca + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].detalle + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].precio + "</td>" +
                         "<td>"+"<input type='text' name='"+data[i].idproducto+"' id='cant' class='form-control input-sm-2' value='1' tabindex='3' placeholder='cant'/>" + "</td>" +


                     "<td>"+
           " <a  class='btn btn-primary' onclick='agregarProducto("+data[i].idproducto+");' id='s' name='agregar' >+</a></td>"+


                    "</tr>";

                $(newRow).appendTo("#resultadomodal tbody");                 



            }




        }  
});
}
 function agregarProducto(idproducto){
    var cantidad=0;
    cantidad=$("input[name="+idproducto+"]").val();

    id=idproducto;


         if (cantidad!==""){
    var accion = "agregarxid";

    $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "../gestionweb/includes/php/procesoDetalle.php",
            data: {"accion":accion,"id":id,"cantidad":cantidad}, 


            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success:function(){
                window.location.href="index.php?controller=ticket&action=index";
            },

        });






  } else{
    alert("ingrese cantidad");
  }

}
```

Osea no se porque si filtro la tabla o me muevo mas abajo no agrega, es como que detecta a cantidad como el primer registro solamnete

Comment: nose... quizas es porque el evento de lanza con con id #cant y es por eso que solo toma el primer elemento, entonces deberias hacer que el evento se lanze por una clase css

Comment: Claro, en todos los elementos de esa clase, y no existe un each para los inputs?

Comment: Lo que veo en tu código es que tu estás lanzando el evento de `keypress` a el elemento #cant, lo que significa que solo tomara el primer elemento con el id #cant que encuentre en el html, Entonces si quieres que todos esos campos de cantidad tengan el evento keypress asociado entonces en lugar de ponerle el id #cant pon .cant (como clase css), de esa manera funcionaria

Comment: si te fijas la clase es "form-control input-sm-2" pero no lo toma, probe con cantidad y tampoco.

Comment: xD, quita el atributo `id` y al atributo `class` agregale otra clase, la clase `cant`, de esta forma quedaria `class='form-control input-sm-2 cant'`

Comment: funciono pero se posiciona en el ultimo elemento xD

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89281/discussion-between-jjoselon-and-caruso).

Comment: ok no hay problema

Answer (score 1):

Funciono usando el atributo "class" como dijo jjoselon y luego usando "first" para posicionarme en  el primer elemento.

```
<input type='text' name='"+filtrado[i].idproducto+"' class='cantidad' value='1' tabindex='3' placeholder='cant'/>
```

Luego hice:

```
('#cod').on('keypress', function(event){

 if (event.keyCode ===13){

       $('.cantidad:first').focus();
     }
 });$('#nombres').on('keypress', function(event){
    if (event.keyCode ===13){

       $('.cantidad:first').focus();
     } });
  },

   500);
 $(document).on('keypress', '.cantidad', function(event){

 if (event.keyCode ===13){

    var id=$(this).attr("name");

  agregarProducto(id);
     }
 });
```

Y anda perfecto.

Muchas gracias